# How to get the week number of the year from the date range in an Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, date, formula

Hi I would like to know a formula where I can convert a grouped date range into the week number of the year. For example column A has the date ranges. I want column B to have the week number. So it will be like the example below

```
    Column A                           Column B
```

31/12/2013 - 06/01/2013............................................Week 1

07/01/2013 - 13/01/2013............................................Week 2

Thanks to anyone who can solve this. Its been bugging me out

Comment: If you have all the date ranges, can't you just fill with Week 1, Week 2 down till Week 52?

Comment: No I dont have all the date ranges so I really need help with this thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use something like that:

```
=(RIGHT(A2,10)*1-41273)/7
```

This takes the last date in that date range, turns it into a number and subtracts 41273 (which is the equivalent of 1st January 2013) and divides the result by 7.

If you want to specifically get `Week 1`, you can either use custom formatting with `"Week "#`, or if you want the literal `Week`, you can use `="Week "&(RIGHT(A2,10)*1-41273)/7`

Comment: @user3045867 You're welcome :) Could you please mark the answer as accepted (by clicking on the tick outline) if you believe it solved your problem? ^^

Comment: Thanks very much. I have also clicked the tick